# Class member method as Template function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, scope

I'm trying to use a class member function as a Template parameter, in the code below, I'd like my "templateOp" to behave as my "nonTemplateOp" method when I create that function passing "memberAdd" instead of "Add".
I've tried a number of iterations, like trying to reference the template parameter as part of the class, but been unsuccessful.
i.e:
      template

In fact, I don't really understand in terms of scope, why the parameter function that works in this case is the one that is out of the class, I'd expect that from a scope point of view, if the template is inside the class, the parameter for the template should be inside the class too.

TL;DR What am I missing for this to work main?

```
test.templateOp<memberAdd>(2);
```

Full code follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
  Test(int value): a(value) {}

  template <int (*T)(int)>
  void templateOp(int opvalue)
  {
    int r = T(opvalue);
    std::cout << "Result is " << r << std::endl;
  }

  void nonTemplateOp(int opvalue)
  {
    int r = memberAdd(opvalue);
    std::cout << "Result is " << r << std::endl;
  }
private:
  int a;
  int memberAdd(int v)
  {
    return v + a;
  }
};

int Add(int v)
{
  return v+1;
}


int main()
{
  Test test(5);
  test.templateOp<Add>(2);
  test.nonTemplateOp(4);
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu While I appreciate the reference to the other question and I imagine this is quite obvious to a seasoned C++ coder, I fail to see how these two questions are related. I imagine that this means that to solve my problem I may need to do something like what's being done in the other question, but I fail to see what. Ultimately one of my main questions lies in the fact that I don't understand the scoping. I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.